# Mongodb find query based on an array field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

**The collection:**

```
{
         "_id" : ObjectId("57506d74c469888f0d631be6"),
         "name" : "mycollection",
         "details" : [ 
             {
                 "date" : "25/03/2020",
                 "number" : "A",
                 "active" : false
              }
        },
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57506d74c469888f0d631usi"),
        "name" : "newcollection",
        "details" : [ 

            {
                "date" : "30/03/2020",
                "number" : "C",
                "active" : false
            } 
        },
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57506d74c4633388f0d631usi"),
        "name" : "mycollection",
        "details" : [ 

            {
                "date" : "31/03/2020",
                "number" : "C",
                "active" : false
            }
        },
    }
```

The find query to get the values based on the active status inside the details field.

I have tried:

```
db.collection.find(
    {"name": "mycollection", "details": {"active": False}})
```

Expected result:
I need the collections where the active is false under details field in each collection. For here record id ObjectId("57506d74c469888f0d631be6") and ObjectId("57506d74c4633388f0d631usi") should be displayed.

Comment: above query seems good to me or you can try this db.collection.find(
    {"name": "mycollection", "details.active": false}}) // case sensitive of boolean value

Comment: It  didn't work@harshitkohli

Comment: hey share expected result as well @Navi

Comment: Added@harshitkohli

Comment: maybe related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: like what if details array also contains some objects with active true and some with false you still require that document?@Navi

Comment: I want the documents which are active false only.@harshitkohli

Answer (score 2):

If details array may have some objects with active = true, and some objects = false, and you need to get only the objects that have active = false, then we can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in aggregation pipeline to filter the details array

your query maybe something like that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "mycollection",
      "details.active": false
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      details: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$details",
          as: "elem",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$elem.active", false]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can [test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xvLEP-hMaPU)

hope it helps

Comment: Can you post it like group by active?

Comment: something like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/77W3WbjBPqu

Comment: No, it is not @Mohammed

Comment: Could you explain how do you mean by group by active?

Answer (score 1):

The docs contain a section on this type of query here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Your query doesn't work because that syntax requires the array to contain that exact object, but documents in your array contain extra fields, so none match.

The query for this case is `db.collection.find({"name": "mycollection", "details.active":  False})`.

Note: this will return all documents where the array contains objects with active==false, but it won't filter the actual arrays to remove any elements with active=true.

Comment: Still no clue@Joseph

Answer (score 0):

The query for mongodb or robomongo is the same as in your case the find() might work, but I choose aggregate which could filter the values.

Example query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([{$match: {'details.active': {$ne: true},"name":"mycollection"}}])
```

Simple. But kindly verify and revert.